# odoo - How to show context in view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

it should be simple I think.

all I want is just to show a context into a field.

ex:

```
<span>the active_id is {context.get('active_id', false)}</span>
```

or

```
<button string="the active_id is: {context.get('active_id',false)}" />
```

I have spent days to look for this, yet no answer has been found. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this field in model definition, for example:

```
context_active_id = fields.Char(default=lambda self: self.env.context.get('active_id', False), store=False, readonly=True)
```

and add that field to the view.

```
<field name='context_active_id' />
```

Comment: You are right that this can be added in a field as you've shown. However, the question seems to be asking how it can be displayed in a `string` (like the button's text). As far as I know that's not possible. If it's not ok to display the field normally, then it may be possible to display the field inline in the form with something like `<span>The active_id is <field name="context_active_id" class="oe_inline"/></span>`

Comment: yes, you are correct @travisw I want to show the value not as a field. I want to show it in a span or button, etc.

Or may be, I need to change my point of view on achieving my goal. tks guys

Comment: im sorry for the late response. I have figured it out, and yes the answer is the same as your answer. Thus I set this as an accepted answer. thanks man.